# Does laptop (linux) automatically shut down/hibernate when suspended on low battery?

Tags: linux, battery, suspend

I am afraid of suspending my laptop, in fear that when it is suspended, and slowly draining battery it will drain it all and damage the battery.

Is there some kind of default hook that will turn of suspended computer when battery will reach critical depletion level, or do I have to implement such safeguards manually, or if it even is possible?

This may be different with different operating systems. Right now I am sporting a brand new net installation of manjaro (distro based on Arch).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does.

You have to tell it what you want to be done on law battery though.
You can configure all this in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

Just read through it. It is self explanatory.
You can choose to measure battery tendency in percentage or time.
Those numbers will trigger warning,  critical warning and action.

Final action can be `PowerOff, Hibernate, HybridSleep`

For obvious reasons there is no point in suspending on law battery.

P.S.

As a side note. It will not damage your battery on full discharge. It will make it last longer. You have to let it discharge completely at least once a week if you want your battery to last. So it is not the battery damage you should be worried about when your computer hits law. The filesystem damage and losing your files - that is your real problem.

So set your upower action to hibernate at 2%. In this case you discharge your battery and keep your filesystem safe. Do not set it for 1% as the power might run out just when it is in the process of writing your memory to swap partition.

Make sure the hibernation actually works manually. Run `sudo systemctl hibernate`. If it does  not work configure the hibernation first which is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop has a battery regulator that will cut power to the motherboard if the battery discharges to a dangerous level.